# Using the Fourier series to calculate $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\text{sin}^{2}(2\pi an)}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-series

Let $-1/2<a<1/2$ I am asked to use the fourier series of the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,\text{ if  } |x|\leq a \\
0,\text{ if  }a<|x|<1/2\end{cases}$$
to calculate $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\text{sin}^{2}(2\pi an)}{n^2}$$

I have noticed that the function $f(x)$ is even. The fourier series of $f(x)$ is $$2a +2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\text{sin}(2\pi an)}{\pi n}\text{cos}(2\pi nx)$$

Since $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f(x)dx=2a,\text{ }\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f(x)\text{cos}(2\pi nx)dx=\frac{\text{sin}(2\pi an)}{\pi n}$$

And I am stuck here, the fourier series does not seem to help since $f(x)$ is even, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe Parseval's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand $sin^2(2\pi na)=\frac{1-cos(4\pi na)}{2}$.

On the other hand $sin(2\pi na).cos(2\pi nx)=\frac{1}{2}(cos(2\pi n(a-x))-cos(2\pi n(a+x)))$ so taking $x=a$ yields $sin(2\pi na).cos(2\pi na)=\frac{1}{2}(1-cos(4\pi na))=sin^2(2\pi na)$.

These both come from trigonometric formulae. Once you are here only need to make a substitution in your series which is convergent to $f$ and use Dini since $f$ is not continuous at $x=a$ (you will state the series is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ in stead of $1$) and a couple more calculations will land you on the desired result.

Comment: Looking further at your problem I can see that the denominator is $n^2$. This means that once you have calculated the series coming from $f$ it will be necessary to apply comparison by taking limits. You will be able to prove that your series is convergent but it won't be possible to find the value of convergence. At least not with this idea stated up here.... maybe you can try changing $n$ for $x$, show uniform convergence and then integrate on $f$ and inside the sum... an idea to get you going... hope this helps!